# Websockets server won't termininate

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I have this python program. If I start it and no clients connect to it, it wont terminate. I tried control+c, control+z, control+pause, control+break, control+shift+/, a prayer to the python gods, but nothing. The only things that will kill it are:

- Pressing control+c, then having a client connect
- control+alt+delete, kill Python.exe

... both of which are very inconvinient.

I'm perfectly fine with ditching those frameworks for others, as long as I don't have to write 60 lines of code for a simple question-response server.

Thanks!

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import time

# socket settings
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # (localhost)
PORT = 62421        


async def TestingStreaming(websocket, path):
    while True:
        await websocket.send("testing")
        try:
            await websocket.recv()
        except:
            print("Client dropped or left.")
            break
        time.sleep(2)


start_server = websockets.serve(TestingStreaming, host="localhost", port=62421)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control+Pause works, but only on PowerShell.